# Get API inside a component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a Card component that takes values from a mapped database array.

The problem is that the **appby** field gets the data as email and I have to make an api get by that email in order to display the name of the person whose email is.

How can I do that so the **ownerId**(it stores the email) field in my database match with the name shown on screen.

In short words, how can i do a **get request** inside a component?

##### code snippet

```js
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { useContext } from "react";
import Button from "../../components/button/button";
import Card from "../../components/card/card";
import Card2 from "../../components/card/card2";
import { RoomContext } from "../../assets/context/RoomContext";
import "./dashboard.scss";
import { MeetingContext } from "../../assets/context/MeetingContext";
import Meetings from "../meetings/meetings";
import axios from "axios";

const Dashboard = () => {
  const room = React.useContext<any[]>(RoomContext);
  const meeting = React.useContext<any[]>(MeetingContext);
  const [hostName, setHostName] = useState({
    host: "",
  });
  useEffect(() => {
    let hostEmail = "";
    meeting.map((dataObj) => (hostEmail = dataObj.ownerId));
    let name = "";
    meeting.map((data) => (name = data.name));
    console.log(name);

    axios.get(`http://localhost:4000/users/${hostEmail}`).then((res) => {
      setHostName({ host: res.data.name });
    });

    // let partEmail = [""];
    // meeting.map((dataObj) => (partEmail = dataObj.participantsId));
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="dashboard">
      <div className="grid-container">
        <div className="left">
          <div className="text">
            <div className="welcome">Welcome back!</div>
            <div className="control">
              Control your schedule, be flexible and appoint new meeting rooms
              with your co-workers whenever you need.
            </div>
            <div className="last">
              LAST UPDATES
              <div className="button">
                <Button className="secondary" name="SCHEDULE A MEETING" />
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div className="cards">
            {meeting.map((dataObj) => {
              return (
                <div className="item">
                  <Card
                    className="card"
                    title={dataObj.name}
                    appFor={dataObj.startDate}
                    appBy={`http://localhost:4000/users/${dataObj.ownerId}`}
                    // cap={dataObj.cap}
                    //time={dataObj.time}
                  />
                </div>
              );
            })}
          </div>
        </div>
        <div className="right">
          <div className="schedule">SCHEDULE A MEETING ROOM</div>
          <div className="rightCards">
            {room.map((dataObj) => {
              return (
                <div className="item">
                  <Card2
                    className="card2"
                    title={dataObj.name}
                    // status={dataObj.status}
                    capacity={dataObj.capacity}
                    // active={dataObj.active}
                  />
                </div>
              );
            })}
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
export default Dashboard;
```

---

I am referring to the **Card** component and the field is **appBy**

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can add `useEffect()` with a dependencies array `[appBy]` in your `card` component.
like this

```js
// Card component
import { useState, useEffect} from 'react'

function Card ({ appBy }){
  const [hostName, setHostName] = useEffect();

  useEffect(()=>{
     axios.get(appBy)
       .then((res) => {
         setHostName({ host: res.data.name });
       });
  }, [appBy]);
  return <>
      <div>{hostName}</div>
    </>
}

export default Card;
```

When `appBy` prop change, the `Card` component will send get reqeust, and render the hostName value to its.